# listview("refresh") is not working for jquery mobile

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I have to append data in template in jquery mobile through ajax call and I am using following libraries and listview function to referesh the existing  with listview("refresh") function but it shows js error i.e. listview is not a function while function is present in below libraries:

```html
<script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/codiqa.ext.js"></script>
```

here is  what I have used

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 jQuery('.pagination_ajax_request').click(function () {
     jQuery.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: this.href,
         dataType: 'html',
         data: 'pagination_ajax_request=1',
         success: function (response) {

             // check if <div id="pagination"><div> exist, means ajax resopnse from post listing page other wise ajax resopnse from topic listing page
             if (jQuery("#pagination").length) {
                 jQuery("#pagination").append(response);
             } else {
                 jQuery("#topic_list").append(response);
                 jQuery("#topic_list").listview("refresh");
             }
             if (ajax_pagination_data['current_page'] != ajax_pagination_data['total_pages'] && ajax_pagination_data['current_page'] != '0') {
                 //update "Load More Topics" OR "Load More Posts" link href value
                 var href = jQuery(".pagination_ajax_request").attr('href');
                 jQuery(".pagination_ajax_request").attr('href', href.replace(/&?trail=\d+/, '&trail=' + ajax_pagination_data['trail']));
             } else {
                 //hide "Load More Topics" OR "Load More Posts" if No topic OR post
                 jQuery(".pagination_ajax_request").hide();
             }
         },
         error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert('An error occurred while processing your request.\n' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
         }
     });
     return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: we need to see ur code before any of us can help you.

Comment: make sure you call it after everything is loaded, i. e. inside $(function(){ .. }); (or after)

Comment: What is coming back in a response? (success: function (response))

Comment: we are getting data in the form of <li> tag with required data which has to be appended in to existing <ul>.

Comment: `#topic-list` is `div` or `ul`?

Answer (score 1):

what data you get from server is important here. and for add dynamic content in list view here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/SS7vJ/)

i think you miss some element or something while adding the li

```
 $('<li>').append('<a href="#">Mercedes</a>').appendTo('#test-listview');
```

or you can try

```
var UI = $('#listViewID');
for(x in data){
   UI.append(data);
}
$('#listViewID').listview("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I reverted back to jquery v1.8.3 and that fixed the issue.

You can try the combination of 1.8.3 and 1.3.1 here: http://jsfiddle.net/dPwzE/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```